# Blue squiggly lines when using SLDS Validator extension in VS Code

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, slds, vs-code

I'm new to LWC and VS Code. I've installed the recommended salesforce extension package which has SLDS Validator in it. But in my html file, it is showing blue squiggly lines under the SLDS class which is actually a valid class provided by salesforce.

[image]

Am I missing something here in settings? Or what do I need to take action to get rid of this. Please someone advise.

Answer (score 1):

SLDS recommends using variable density classes so when you use `slds-p-around__medium`, It recommends using `slds-var-p-around__medium`. Because of this you are getting this line. This line appears if there is any error/recommendation by any extension. If you hover over that statement you will get message for that line

Comment: It's not causing any issue actually. Also the lwc is already an existing one which works perfectly. After retrieving the source, I'm seeing these squiggly lines.

Comment: This is not an issue. This is just a suggestion by SLDS Validator extension to use slds-var-p-around__medium. You are seeing this lines as suggestions by extension.

Comment: Though I tried the quick fix suggested on hovering, still the lines are there

Comment: The quick fix doesn't work quite right yet, if you add the `-var-` in the class, it will vanish the warnings.